# How to specify video dimensions in a video with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

this program determines when there is a dramatic change in pixels in a video and prints out at which frame and at what millisecond the change occurred. I am using the millisecond value in another program to save an image of that instant in the video then analyze that image to determine the height of the person in the video. The problem is that the video resolution is really small. The video length spans along the whole screen when played in my media player but the height is only about three inches. When I save an image based on the millisecond value I get the image is pitch black because that is what is above and below the small video frame. I would like to change the video size that the video is seen across the entire screen and that when I save an image from the video based on the millisecond value I do not get black. This is a crucial part of my project. Please help me. Thank you very much.

I am getting this error: 
TypeError: Expected CvCapture for argument 'capture'

This is how I have gone about changing the height and width of the video:

width  = cv.SetCaptureProperty(capfile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)

```
height = cv.SetCaptureProperty(capfile,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)



import sys
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np


# Advanced Scene Detection Parameters
INTENSITY_THRESHOLD = 16  # Pixel intensity threshold (0-255), default 16
MINIMUM_PERCENT     = 95   # The minimum amount of pixels allowed to be       below threshold.
BLOCK_SIZE          = 32    # Number of rows to sum per iteration.


def main():

capfile = 'camera20.h264'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open(capfile)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print "Fatal error - could not open video %s." % capfile
    return
else:
    print "Parsing video %s..." % capfile

# Do stuff with cap here.

width  = cv.SetCaptureProperty(capfile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
height = cv.SetCaptureProperty(capfile,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
print "Video Resolution: %d x %d" % (width, height)

# Allow the threshold to be passed as an optional, second argument to the script.
threshold = 50

 print "Detecting scenes with threshold = %d" % threshold
 print "Min. pixels under threshold = %d %%" % MINIMUM_PERCENT
 print "Block/row size = %d" % BLOCK_SIZE
 print ""

 min_percent = MINIMUM_PERCENT / 100.0
 num_rows    = BLOCK_SIZE
 last_amt    = 0     # Number of pixel values above threshold in last frame.
 start_time  = cv2.getTickCount()  # Used for statistics after loop.

 while True:
     # Get next frame from video.
     (rv, im) = cap.read()
     if not rv:   # im is a valid image if and only if rv is true
         break

     # Compute # of pixel values and minimum amount to trigger fade.
     num_pixel_vals = float(im.shape[0] * im.shape[1] * im.shape[2])
     min_pixels     = int(num_pixel_vals * (1.0 - min_percent))

     # Loop through frame block-by-block, updating current sum.
     frame_amt = 0
     curr_row  = 0
     while curr_row < im.shape[0]:
        # Add # of pixel values in current block above the threshold.
        frame_amt += np.sum(
            im[curr_row : curr_row + num_rows,:,:] > threshold )
        if frame_amt > min_pixels:  # We can avoid checking the rest of the
            break                   # frame since we crossed the boundary.
        curr_row += num_rows

    # Detect fade in from black.
    if frame_amt >= min_pixels and last_amt < min_pixels:
        print "Detected fade in at %dms (frame %d)." % (
            cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC),
            cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) )

    # Detect fade out to black.
    elif frame_amt < min_pixels and last_amt >= min_pixels:
        print "Detected fade out at %dms (frame %d)." % (
            cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC),
            cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) )

    last_amt = frame_amt      # Store current mean to compare in next iteration.

 # Get # of frames in video based on the position of the last frame we read.
 frame_count = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
 # Compute runtime and average framerate
 total_runtime = float(cv2.getTickCount() - start_time) /   cv2.getTickFrequency()
 avg_framerate = float(frame_count) / total_runtime

 print "Read %d frames from video in %4.2f seconds (avg. %4.1f FPS)." % (
     frame_count, total_runtime, avg_framerate)

 cap.release()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're mixing new and old syntax. Try using this:

```
cv2.VideoCapture.set(propId, value) → retval
```

instead of this:

```
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, property_id, value) → retval
```